# Rewrite content in ember.js controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a model `consultation` with belong:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    records: DS.hasMany('record', { async: true }),
})
```

And `ObjectController` with this belong `consultation` -> `records`

How I can rewrite `records` values in controller, I tried do like this

```
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    records: function(){ /*do some logic*/return this.records}.bind(this)
});
```

but got error `Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed function () { [native code] }`

Also little confused me default `content` property in `ObjectController` which store values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're defining `records` as a function (`bind` creates a function); what are you trying to accomplish? Nope, you can't loop over that! If you're trying to create a modified version of `records` on the model, then do something like

```
--controller
    records: function() {
        return this.get('model.records').filter(...);
    }.property('model.records.@each')
```

or whatever suits your fancy.

Note `model`===`content`; it's the underlying data the controller is controlling, often coming from the server, and most often set up in the route's `setupController`.